# Memcache not getting deleted through Ajax Call to Controller

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, memcached

I have a MVC structure in one project where there is a dropdown on change of which I am calling a Controller as follows..

**Javascript Code**

```
function getData(newSelection)//This will get called on change of dropdown
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/controller_name/perform',
        data: {
            'dropDownSelection': newSelection
        },
        success: function(data){     
            //alert(data);  /* always "failed" */                                      
            window.location.href=window.location;
        }
});
```

Now, in perform action (i.e. method named as PerformAction) the call is coming properly.

**Perform Action**

```
        /* somehow I am forming $key; trust me, its formed correct */
        $cache = Zend_Registry::get("cache");

        if($cache->delete($key))
            echo ("success");
        else
            echo ("failed");//this is what always returned
        exit;
```

But at some code which executes after above code, I am checking whether cache exits or not, then it is showing as exists.

**Code where i am checking**

```
        $cache = Zend_Registry::get("cache");
       //After building $key.                       
       //$cache->delete($key);    //Here it works

        $cacheResult = $cache->get($key);
        if (!empty($cacheResult)) ) {
           //exit("here it is coming, which I dont want for certain situation");
            return $cacheResult;
        }
        $reslut = /* Now I am building new result as per new selection from dropdown */
        $cache->set($key,$result,MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,300);
        return $result;  //i want this to be returned instead of cached result
```

So this is the scene. 
I want to get fresh result that is built using new selection from dropdown, if I remove comment from $cache->delete($key); above it will always remove cache, but I dont want this.
I want to know where I am going wrong OR is that beacause of AJAX ?

Comment: there should be no problem with AJAX call..have you tried unset()..??

Comment: how can I unset that? like this... unset($cache->get($key)) ?

Comment: I havent used unset for cache yet. I have used unset for only normal variable, arrays, etc.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-2752 read this. Bdw you can also unset it by `unset($cache[$key])`

Comment: I tried unset($cache[$key]) but, same result. It is not removing cache.

Comment: guess what.. $cache->flush(); is working, but it removes whole cache, I want to remove only cache of that key.

Comment: But `unset($cache[$key])` should work.. check by var_dump that what are you getting true or false `var_dump(unset($cache[$key]))`.. if you are getting true then problem is somewhere else..